# Django ORM get only field in foreignkey relationship

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-orm

I have database tables like this

```
class Message(models.Model):
   text      = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   length    = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   receivers = models.IntegerField()

class Network(models.Model):
  name    = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  is_down = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class SMSLog(models.Model):
   receiver = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   message  = models.ForeignKey(Message, related_name='log')
   network  = models.ForeignKey(Network)
   status   = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I need just three fields in my query i.e. text, log__receiver and log__network__name. I tried like this

```
Message.objects.all().prefetch_related('log').only('text', 'log__receiver', 'log__network__name')
```

The above query does not work. How to do query like above in django ORM ?

Comment: Try `.values` rather than `only`

Comment: Try: Message.objects.all().prefetch_related('log', 'log__network').only('text', 'log__receiver', 'log__network__name')

Comment: that does not work I have already tried.

Comment: is the table name sms_log or log? model name seems to be `SMSLog`.
try this:
Message.objects.select_related('log').only('text', 'log__receiver', 'log__network__name')

Comment: I tried this also does not work and finally switched to .values()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment: Use `values` instead of `only`:

```
Message.objects.all().prefetch_related('log').values('text', 'log__receiver', 'log__network__name')
```

Comment: Added as an answer so it might help someone else.